# Error thrown but no error is seen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" on line 1030 but just look at this line. Everything is OK:

```
<input type="text" class="text is_required validate form-control" data-validate="isPostCode"  name="postcode" id="postcode" value="00-000" onblur="$('#postcode').val($(#postcode').val().toUpperCase());" style="width:150px" placeholder="kod pocztowy" />
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: `Everything is OK` No, it's not. By simply looking at the highlight syntax in the question I already saw the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a single quote:

```
onblur="$('#postcode').val($('#postcode').val().toUpperCase());
//                   here   ^^^
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for stupid question.